# JQuery cancel dropdown / slide down of list on quick hover action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

Is there any way of cancelling drop-down of a list when the mouse only grace the hover area?

I want to drop down / slide down the list when the mouse has been on the UL for about one second.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off toggling the drop down on click rather than on hover. [This](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/) explains why.

If you have to do this on hover, you could simply set up a timer.

```
$('.myElement').hover(function() {
    var myElement = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(myElement.is(':hover'))
        {
            // Do drop down here
        }
    }, 1000);
})
```

Edit: This may not work past jQuery 1.8, another way would be to use a class:

```
$('.toggleDropdown').hover(function() {
    $('ul', this).addClass('hover');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.hover').stop().slideDown(500);
    }, 1000);
}, function() {
    $('ul', this).removeClass('hover');
})
```

Like so: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3m4t/).